Centos 7 -- enable core dump for user, not system?
All of the discussion I have seen regarding enabling core dumps on Centos 7 seem to assume that you are root, and you are enabling core dumps systemwide.
Can I, as a user, enable core dumps just for myself, dumping the core file in my own home directory?   Or is this something that can only be done by root?
Also: is this a problem unique to Centos?

You can set per-user behaviour via ulimit, more specifically you can say how large the core files can be - but you still need to enable core dumps on the system.
Only the root user can control these settings.
This is common to all the Linux distributions I have used.
